# A Java program with a loop that allows the user to enter a series of integers, then displays the smallest and largest numbers + the average

Tags: java, loops, average

I've got an assignment that requires me to use a loop in a program that asks the user to enter a series of integers, then displays the smallest and largest numbers AND gives an average. I'm able to write the code that allows the user to enter however many integers they like, then displays the smallest and largest number entered. What stumps me is calculating the average based on their input. Can anyone help? I'm sorry if my code is a little janky. This is my first CS course and I'm by no means an expert.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.*;

public class LargestSmallest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)    
    
    {
        int number, largestNumber, smallestNumber, amountOfNumbers;
        double sum, average;
        String inputString;

        inputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an integer, or enter -99 to stop.");
        number = Integer.parseInt(inputString);

        largestNumber = number;
        smallestNumber = number;

        sum = 0;

        for (amountOfNumbers = 1; number != -99; amountOfNumbers++)
            {
                inputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an integer, or enter -99 to stop.");
                number = Integer.parseInt(inputString);
                

                if (number == -99)
                    break;
                if (number > largestNumber)
                    largestNumber = number;
                if (number < smallestNumber)
                    smallestNumber = number;  
                
                sum += number;
            }

            average = sum / amountOfNumbers;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The smallest number is: " + smallestNumber + ".");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The largest number is: " + largestNumber + ".");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The average off all numbers is: " + average + ".");


    }
}
```

Comment: You have an average calculation there already. What problem are you observing with the code you have posted?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do an extra

```
inputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an integer, or enter -99 to stop.");
    number = Integer.parseInt(inputString);
```

at the beginning. You don't count that in a sum. That's why you get unexpected results.

The fix would be:

1. replace the declarations line with:

   int number = 0, largestNumber, smallestNumber, amountOfNumbers;
2. Remove

   inputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an integer, or enter -99 to stop.");
   number = Integer.parseInt(inputString);
   That go before the loop
3. Replace `for (amountOfNumbers = 0` with `for (amountOfNumbers = 1`

Comment: I highly recomment to learn to use debugger. It is super easy and would let you observ variables in runtime and save you tons of time with small mistakes like this one.

Answer (score 0):

> This is my first CS course

Then allow me to show you a different way to do your assignment.

- Don't use [JOptionPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) to get input from the user. Use a [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html) instead.
- Rather than use a `for` loop, use a [do-while](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) loop.
- Usually you declare variables when you need to use them so no need to declare all the variables at the start of the method. However, be aware of [variable scope](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html).

(Notes after the code.)

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LargestSmallest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        int largestNumber = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int smallestNumber = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int number;
        double sum = 0;
        int amountOfNumbers = 0;
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter an integer, or enter -99 to stop: ");
            number = stdin.nextInt();
            if (number == -99) {
                break;
            }
            if (number > largestNumber) {
                largestNumber = number;
            }
            if (number < smallestNumber) {
                smallestNumber = number;  
            }
            sum += number;
            amountOfNumbers++;
        } while (number != -99);

        if (amountOfNumbers > 0) {
            double average = sum / amountOfNumbers;
            System.out.printf("The smallest number is: %d.%n", smallestNumber);
            System.out.printf("The largest number is: %d.%n", largestNumber);
            System.out.printf("The average of all numbers is: %.4f.%n", average);
        }
    }
}
```

- `largestNumber` is initialized to the smallest possible number so that it will be assigned the first entered number which must be larger than `largestNumber`.
- Similarly, `smallestNumber` is initialized to the largest possible number.
- If the first value entered is -99 then `amountOfNumbers` is zero and dividing by zero throws [ArithmeticException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html) (but maybe you haven't learned about [exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html) yet). Hence, after the `do-while` loop, there is a check to see whether at least one number (that isn't -99) was entered.
- You don't need to use [printf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) to display the results. I'm just showing you that option.